# Подскажите библиотеку для LSTM моделей

Tags: нейронные-сети, поиск-библиотек

Для прогнозирования временного ряда модели авторегрессии и распределённого лага хочу воспользоваться рекуррентной нейронной сетью с долгосрочной памятью. Должна быть возможность задать количество нейронов в LSTM слоях, в агрегирующем слое, а также указания функции активации (для агрегирующего слоя хочу взять ReLU, для выходного - линейную функцию).

Язык реализации - C++/C#, платформа - Windows.

Так же интересует как следует правильно подготовить входные данные и обучающую выборку для такой сети. Подойдёт ли MinMax нормализация?

Answer (score 3):

1. [Keras](https://keras.io/examples/lstm_stateful/)
2. [deeplearning4j](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-nn-recurrent)
3. [pytorch](https://www.jessicayung.com/lstms-for-time-series-in-pytorch/)
4. [tensorflow](https://rubikscode.net/2018/03/26/two-ways-to-implement-lstm-network-using-python-with-tensorflow-and-keras/)
5. [CNTK от Microsoft](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk_106a_lstm_timeseries_with_simulated_data.html)

И если вдруг охота самому на С# подвиг совершить:

[Understanding LSTM Cells Using C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt846470.aspx)

Comment: А что на счёт масштабирования данных скажите? Если задача прогнозирование, значит в итоге нужно определить будущие значения ряда. На входе выполняется масштабирование данных, на выходе получается какое-то число от 0 до 1. Как определить какое это будет конкретно значение ряда?

Comment: @D.Stark на вход получаете данные из какой-то точки, на выходе - также. На сколько я понимаю, нужно указывать на какой срок делаете предсказание в отдельной фиче. Могу ошибаться

Comment: Я имею ввиду как значение от 0 до 1 преобразовать в значение ряда? Ну ряд, допустим, от 0 до 100 изменяется.

Comment: Все примеры, которые вы мне предлагаете, выполнены на python. Deeplearning4j вообще, на сколько я понял, не предоставляет интерфейса для C++. На сайте CNTK вообще не нашёл толковой документации по C# Managed API. Классы, используемые в примерах на GitHub не описаны в документации. Крупные библиотеки вроде tensorflow и keras я бы не хотел использовать, т. к. ищу что то более специализированное под мою задачу (построение LSTM RNN), да и направлены они больше на python.

Comment: По поводу масштабирования данных ответа так и не дождался...

Answer (score 1):

microsoft ml.net

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/machinelearning-ai/ml-dotnet

даже на русском, для начинающих перевели, плюс Майкрософту

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/